# meteor pagination,change the source

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite

i'm trying to do pagination in meteor and most of the packages i found have source as a collection.
these are some of the packages i found [this](https://github.com/huyinghuan/meteor-pagination-mini),[this](https://github.com/airlok/meteor-pagination) and [this](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-paginated-subscription)

These all are having collection as a source like

```
page.create(People.find().count());
```

and

```
Meteor.publish('posts', function(limit) {
  return Posts.find({}, {limit: limit});
});
```

and

```
Pagination.collection(People.find({}).fetch(), options);
```

my source is from a api like this

```
var result = skimlinks_query({
    searchFor: pro_id,
    fq: "country:US"
});
```

Is there any other packages to achieve pagination with this source.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/TimHeckel/meteor-paginator

Comment: i think that too is taking collection as source